# Binary Character in QR code

Tags: qr-code, binary-data

It seem QR code is able to store Binary character(8bits) but I can't find anyway to do it.
Anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use QR code's Byte Mode to encode these bytes. That's all. Note that readers will want to interpret these bytes as text, so there's no chance that readers will understand your binary data as binary data (like, an encoded image). But maybe you have a custom reader that does something special with it.