# Is it possible to encode a qr code from a list of signed integers where each integer would represent a byte in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, qr-code

Let us consider the following

`list: [-127,37,92]`

Trying to store it in byte mode (using segno and qrcode libraries in python) would have each character represented by a byte. This means that the whole list would take up 12 bytes.

Is it possible to encode a qr code where each byte represents a signed integer?

So `-127` represented by one byte, `37` represented by another byte and 92 represented by another byte.  This would mean that only `3` bytes are being used to store the information.

Comment: There's this question about a [Binary Character in QR code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294277/binary-character-in-qr-code), but I don't think it would let you specify that each byte should be interpreted as a signed integer.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried to use so far? Show any errors or output you got from this code. Can you link to the documentation for the libraries you are trying to use?

Comment: What type of QR code do you want to store? https://www.beaconstac.com/types-of-qr-codes-examples And why only 3 bytes when you can store 7,000 ?